# trying to set a "No Reply" address as the From address

Tags: email, inboundemail

when i send Outbound message from Salesfroce ,i need the from Address is "No reply"

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to clarify.  Are you trying to set a "No Reply" address as the From address?  Please [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000355732&type=1) link and create a default No-reply email address for your org.

Description:
From **Setup**, enter **Organization-Wide Addresses** in the **Quick Find** box and select it.
Find **Special Purpose Organization-Wide Email Addresses**, and enter the desired email address as the default No-Reply address. Then, follow the steps sent to your email inbox to verify your org’s default No-Reply address.

Comment: hello C. Praveenkumar thanks for your help .can you help a bit more. Suppose anyone trying to reply on "No reply " mail,   so  is it  possible to not allow end-user to send replies?

Comment: @Gaurav most noreply email addresses are real email addresses. People just don't reply to emails sent to them. You can do the same, as there's nothing you can do to stop someone from sending it emails.